# Using JQuery with Master Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, master-pages

I am trying to use JQuery in Master Page. I do not get any error, but the JQuery is working.
I am trying to use Table Sorter function.

```
MasterFile:
    <head runat="server">
    <script src="../js/libs/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     $( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
    $(".tablesort").tablesorter();
     });
        </script> 


.cs FIle (Using Master Page)
<uc1:CERDisplayControl ID="displayControl" runat="server" class="tablesort" />
```

When I try to load the page, I do not get any error but the contents are not loaded properly.

Comment: why are you providing `$` as a parameter for the ready function? This is unneeded and could be causing averse effects

Answer (score 0):

The `$` in the parameter for the function handler is probably redefining `$` as something other than the normal value of the jQuery object. Remove it from the parameters and see what you get.

`$(document).ready(function($ /* <-- here*/ ){ }`

Sample:

```
$(function(){  /*this is shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){ */
    $(".tablesort").tablesorter();
});
```